# SwiftでUIAlertControllerの独自クラスを作りたい

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

コードを整理する目的でUIAlertControllerを使った独自クラスを作りたいと思っています。
限定的な内容なので、OriginalAlertController内に要素（テキストやアクションなど）は全て突っ込んでおいて、あとは初期化するだけにできればと思っていました。

例えば利用するのViewControllerから下記のように呼び出したいです。

```
let alertController = OriginalAlertController()
presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

そこで下記のようなクラスを作ろうかとしましたが、「must call a designated initializer of the superclass」のエラーが発生します。

```
import UIKit

class OriginalAlertController: UIAlertController{

    let titleStr = "タイトル"
    let messageStr = "メッセージ"

    override init() {
        super.init(title: self.titleStr, message: self.messageStr, preferredStyle: .Alert) // Error: Must call a designated initializer of the superclass
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

調べるとconvenience initializerは呼べないということでしたが、
どのようにすれば同じような目的を達成できそうでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

その用途であれば、サブクラスを作る必要がないような気がします……。ので、関数を。

```
func createConnectionAlertController() -> UIAlertController {
    let controller = UIAlertController(title: "タイトル", message: "メッセージ", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    controller.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:"はい", style:.Default){
        action in NSLog("はいが押された")
        })

    return controller
}
```

**[UPDATE]**

swfitらしく`extension`でも良いかもしれません。

```
extension UIAlertController {
    class func connectionAlert() -> UIAlertController {
        let controller = UIAlertController(title: "タイトル", message: "メッセージ", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        controller.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:"はい", style:.Default){
        action in NSLog("はいが押された")
        })
        return controller
    }
}

// in UIViewController
let controller = UIAlertController.connectionAlert()
presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: 仰るとおりでした。結局のところUIAlertControllerの処理はサブクラス化すること自体があまり良くないやり方だと感じました。

Answer (score 2):

以下でできました。

```
import Foundation
final class ConnectionErrorAlertController : UIAlertController{

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    let yesAction = UIAlertAction(title:"はい", style:.Default){
      action in NSLog("はいが押された")
    }
    addAction(yesAction)
  }

  class func getConnectionAlert() -> ConnectionErrorAlertController {
    return ConnectionErrorAlertController(title: "title", message: "msg", preferredStyle: .Alert)
  }
}
// 呼び出し方
let instance = ConnectionErrorAlertController.getConnectionAlert()
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。ご提案頂いた方法を試してみたところaddTextFieldWithConfigurationHandlerを使って、入力をフォーム付きAlertを作りたかったのですが、init
しないのでpreferredStyleがセットされていないためか、'Text fields can only be added to an alert controller of style UIAlertControllerStyleAlert'
というクラッシュエラーが出てしまいました。
var preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle { get }とかかれているので、initでしか設定できなそうです。

Comment: Initializerで初期化するのはいかがでしょうか？

let instance = ConnectionErrorAlertController(title: "title", message: "msg", preferredStyle: .Alert)// 3つ目の引数で初期化

Answer (score 2):

回答になっているか解りませんが、察するに以下のような方法でも良いのかなと思いました。

```
class OriginalAlert {

    let titleStr = "タイトル"
    let messageStr = "メッセージ"

    var controller: UIAlertController {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: titleStr, message: messageStr, preferredStyle: .Alert)
        alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler(nil)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
        // ...
        return alert
    }
}
```

呼び出し方:

```
let alert = OriginalAlert()
presentViewController(alert.controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: そういう書き方も出来るんですね！非常に参考になりました。